# Minimum Detectable Signal of Camera and Improvements to Minimum Detectable Signal through pulsing

Tags: signal, signal-processing, camera, small-signal, pixels

My goal is to determine for specific signal measSig, what is the largest background signal backSig I could receive and still be able to detect my measurement Signal? I know that camera modules typically come with a pixel dynamic range which is the ratio of the pixel full well capacity and the read out noise. Would this be the same dynamic range I use in order to determine what is the largest background signal I can have and still be capable of detecting my measurement signal?

Furthermore are there other things I need to consider such as the number of bits used by the ADC. At some point it seems certain that the difference between the small measurement signal and the large signal will be out of range for the N bits in the ADC.

Finally, considering that the pixel dynamic range is limited by readout noise could I improve this dynamic range by potentially pulsing my measurement signal across multiple frames at a given frequency and then taking an fft of that pixel across time? Because of the fact that the noise should be random I can push it further down by measuring with a signal of a known spectral shape / frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would this be the same dynamic range I use in order to determine what is the largest background signal I can have and still be capable of detecting my measurement signal?

Yes that is the same dynamic range.  However, there are two caveats here:

1. If your background signal is located on the same pixel (so a grey background with an image superimposed), then the shot noise from that background will be superimposed onto your signal.  Thus your actual noise would be the quadrature addition of the shot noise and the read noise.  If your background is not located on the same pixels, then you can ignore its shot noise.
2. This is assuming you process each pixel independently.  If you're willing to spatially average you can extend your dynamic range.

> Furthermore are there other things I need to consider such as the number of bits used by the ADC. At some point it seems certain that the difference between the small measurement signal and the large signal will be out of range for the N bits in the ADC.

If the camera has fewer ADC bits than required, yes.  For this reason, cameras usually let you set the conversion gain, so you can adjust that as needed to get the feature of interest into your dynamic range.  Alternatively, you can take two frames, one at high gain and one at low gain and fuse them into a higher dynamic range image.

> Finally, considering that the pixel dynamic range is limited by readout noise could I improve this dynamic range by potentially pulsing my measurement signal across multiple frames at a given frequency and then taking an fft of that pixel across time? Because of the fact that the noise should be random I can push it further down by measuring with a signal of a known spectral shape / frequency.

This is called lock in detection, and yes you can certainly do it, although it is less common on cameras than on faster detectors like photodiodes.